# Using CreateCSharpAssemblyInfo throws an error : FAKE- F#MAKE

Tags: f#, f#-3.0, f#-fake

I am using "CreateCSharpAssemblyInfo" function of FAKE for updating AssemblyInfo.cs.
But I am getting error , i.e.

```
  2) CS0579: Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs: Duplicate 'AssemblyProductAttribute' attribute
  3) CS0579: Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs: Duplicate 'AssemblyCompanyAttribute' attribute
  4) CS0579: Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs: Duplicate 'AssemblyCopyrightAttribute' attribute
  5) CS0579: Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs: Duplicate 'AssemblyVersionAttribute' attribute
  6) CS0579: Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs: Duplicate 'AssemblyFileVersionAttribute' attribute
```

here is the code that I am using :

```
let assemblyInfo = [
  Attribute.Title "My Project"
  Attribute.Product "My Product"
  Attribute.Company "XYZ"
  Attribute.Copyright "Copyright XYZ"
  Attribute.Version "14.8"
  Attribute.FileVersion "13.9"
]

Target "BuildApp" (fun _ ->
  CreateCSharpAssemblyInfo  "./Source Code/Project/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs" assemblyInfo
  !! "/Source Code/Project.sln"
      |> MSBuildReleaseExt buildDir [("SolutionDir", currentPath @@ "\BuildTools")] "Build"
      |> Log "AppBuild-Output:"
)
```

I am not getting the reason of this error .

I'm new to FAKE and have not used F# much, so forgive me if this should be obvious.

If anyone can help , that would be really helpful.

Comment: `CreateCSharpAssemblyInfo` isn't throwing an error, MSBuild is. Once it fails, open the solution in VS and build there - it will also fail. You should be able to find the problem - you may have those attributes defined in another file the project is referencing, for example.

Comment: dotnet core is automatically generating those assembly attributes for you, which is conflicting with the ones from FAKE

Comment: @Charles Mager: it is not failing from VS .

Comment: @Foole : yes , I think this might be the reason for this , so is there any solution for this ?

Comment: @johnfernandes There are a few options - add the attribute values to your project file, specify them as MSBuild parameters, or disable attribute generation (I have not been able to do this last one)

Comment: Also one could delete all generated `AssemblyInfo.cs` files and instead create new with the desired attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `CreateCSharpAssemblyInfoWithConfig`argument? It allows for an additional parameter:

```
CreateCSharpAssemblyInfoWithConfig
        assemblyInfoFile
        attributes
        (AssemblyInfoFileConfig(generateClass=false))
```

Alternatively, the `UpdateAttribute` would do a similar thing (in my case all developers work in Visual Studio and it is safe to assume default `AssemblyInfo.cs` files would be auto-generated).
From the [doc](http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/apidocs/fake-assemblyinfofile.html):

> Update a set of attributes in an AssemblyInfo file. Fails if any attribute is not found.

See below example:

```
Target "UpdateAssemblyInfo" (fun _ -> 
    let csProjectDirs =
        !! "**/**/*.csproj"
        |> Seq.map (directory >> directoryInfo)

    let attributes =
        [ 
            Attribute.Title "My Project"
            Attribute.Product "My Product"
            Attribute.Company "XYZ"
            Attribute.Copyright "Copyright XYZ"
         ]
    let applyAssemblyInfo (projDir:DirectoryInfo) = 
        let assemblyInfoFile = projDir.FullName @@ "Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs"
        clearReadOnly assemblyInfoFile
        UpdateAttributes
            assemblyInfoFile
            attributes

    csProjectDirs |> Seq.iter applyAssemblyInfo
)
```